# Верстка макетов с PSD

Tags: html, css

Народ подскажите пожалуйста как научится верстать макеты с psd. Подскажите что именно нужно знать в HTML/CSS. Я пока начинающий и не знаю с чего начинать. В HTML знаю только что такое атрибуты,теги,и.т.д.Селекторы не знаю вообще. Читал книгу Трепачева Дмитрия  HTML/CSS ДЛЯ Начинающих.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/202408/

Answer (score 2):

Я бы Вам посоветовал читать и сразу практиковаться. Попробуйте сверстать одностраничный сайт, изначально используя минимальное количество CSS-кода. Как вы разберетесь с одной страницей, добавляйте прямо к ней еще одну и т.д.

Лично мне очень сильно помогли YouTube каналы "BrainsCloud" и "Фрилансер по жизни". На них авторы полноценно показывают как верстать сайты и рассказывают уловки в этом деле, которые помогут Вам в будущем.

PS: Не подумайте ничего, просто мне лично мне нужна визуализация и разжевывание действий, которые описываются в примере. И да, написал ответом, потому что stackoverflow не дает писать комментарии начинающему пользователю.